# Push Data From One Instance of SuiteCRM to Another

Tags: php, suitecrm

I currently have a module named **Master**. I need to push data from that module to the master module within another instance of SuiteCRM.

How can I achieve that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an export option in most modules. If you select all the master records in the list view you will have an option to export them to csv. These can then be imported into the other instance.

Alternatively you can dump out the master and master_cstm tables using whatever DB tools you use and import the resulting SQL file into the new instance.

Comment: How to pass data through rest api ??

Comment: @divya Can you be more specific? What problem are you having using the API?

Comment: I just want to pass some values from one suitecrm instance to another suitecrm instance.Example, i want to pass user details,by what method i can pass?

Comment: The `set_entry` method will allow you to create/update records. [Info here](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Method_Calls/index.html)

Comment: can u give me some example?

Comment: @divya Is there anything you have tried already? Creating a sync between two SuiteCRM instances is not something I can describe in a Stack Overflow comment. If there are specific issues you are having using the API or setting up the sync I'll be happy to help however.